# Can I use wordpress on an existing webpage?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a static website using HTML, bootstrap, and CSS for a company. After my internship is over, they will not have a developer to maintain and update their website. I was wondering if they could use wordpress to maintain and update their website since they do not have any knowledge in web developing. I visited the wordpress website but I couldn't find enough information on it.

Comment: yep. that is what it's for. wordpress is great for companies with a low IT budget.

Comment: Nop. But if you don't have time (or knowledge) to make a wordpress theme, you can advise them to use a software such as dreamweaver (or any html wysiwyg editor)

Comment: well, a minimal wordpress theme is little more than a static html page.. so depends on how u look at it.. if u can build static HTML, learning themeing should be trivial.

Comment: well.. except that it's not static..

Comment: im confused... so is wordpress strictly for dynamic web pages/applications? And I will look into dreamweaver

Comment: don't let the lingo confuse you. if you implemented wordpress, it would no longer be considered 'static'. dreamweaver is quite possibly the worst thing to ever happen to the web. don't listen to that guy. plus it's super expensive. Go with WP. pick a simple theme and edit it to your liking. and your boss will be super impressed. trust me.

Comment: If you want to maintain a static site but still be able to generate new pages occasionally, try considering Jekyll. IMHO WordPress is too bloated if the company is only updating some pages and on a non-regular basis. Since you already have the HTML and the CSS, porting it over to Jekyll is very simple. Easier than creating a WordPress (child) theme that requires some kind of maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress and static sites are different animals and different approaches to the web. WordPress is a Content Management System (CMS) that stores content in a database and the design a combination of static files and data in the database. A static site stores content and design in static files.

Changes in a WordPress site - content and design - take place primarily in the WordPress admin backend running on the webserver. Static sites use text editors - or GUIs like Dreamweaver - on a client machine and are transferred to the webserver.

That said, *if you main goal is the ability for people to easily change most content*, WordPress is a better way to go than a page builder and FTP uploader like Dreamweaver.

With WordPress, users can learn the backend much like they would learn how to use Word, and make text changes and move graphical elements on a page in the editor. This is something that office staff can continue with after you're gone; and WordPress is popular enough that people may already know how to use it.

It sounds like WordPress is the long-term solution for what you want to and leave the company with. There are people who look down on WordPress because it is a CMS, because it is popular, etc. But it does make the web easy for people.

Everything you need to know is here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page

Take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development to learn how themes are used in WordPress.

**The main issue you will deal with** is a WordPress theme: a theme is the overall design of the site. You can't use Dreamweaver to create a theme for WordPress.

So take a look at the Theme Development link above, and then decide if you want to try and create a brand new theme, or use an existing, free theme from https://wordpress.org/themes/ . There are also many commercial (paid) themes available for Wordpress; Google will show those to you.

**If you want to use Bootstrap**, Google (and the WordPress theme Directory linked above) will show you several basic "boilerplate" WordPress themes built on Bootstrap that will be customizable and are a great way to start with a WordPress theme based on Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CMS like WordPress will make content updates easy for them. Code changes will be tough for them any way you go.

Your biggest consideration is **how it is hosted**. Since you are doing a custom site, WordPress.com is out of the question. But you might want to look at something like [Pantheon](http://pantheon.io) or [WP-Engine](http://www.wpengine.com), which are more turnkey WordPress platforms. Those will manage the WordPress instance and it's required LAMP stack components for them after you are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Making a "theme" with basic functions such as titles and content is fairly easy. If you code that(there are plenty of free tutorial of that) they can maintain the basic content. Your menus, headers and footers will be tougher but as long as they can edit the content with a WYSIWYG editor, it will be fine.